# How do I grab / properly set item values (not text) from a listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, telerik

I've got 2 listboxes that work together as a data transfer control.
So I can move items left to right and vice versa etc by the use of 2 buttons, and then by using a 3rd button, I need to grab the values (not the text portion) of the items on one of the lists.

Visually everything looks fine. Items move back and forth with no problem. But when it's time to grab the items, no luck. . .

for one of the clicks I have:

```
Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListDataItem item = new Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListDataItem(lstRight.SelectedItem.Text, lstRight.SelectedItem.Value);
List<Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListDataItem> left = new List<Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListDataItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < lstLeft.Items.Count; i++)
{
    Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListDataItem z = new Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListDataItem(lstLeft.Items[i].Text, lstLeft.Items[i].Value);
    left.Add(z);
}
left.Add(item);
lstLeft.DataSource = left;
lstRight.Items.Remove(lstRight.SelectedItem);
```

I've tried using it with telerik, with the reqular ms listbox etc., but no luck. I just can't get to the value after. I can't simply insert an item either, "Item cannot be inserted when it is in data-bound mode" stuff.. .

Anyone know how to solve this or tell me where I'm going wrong? I've been stuck for a bit on this and just can't see what I'm doing wrong .. .